# Chrome Extension and Identity API: Upon login attempt to Facebook user is asked for username + password although he is already logged on FB

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, authentication, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm developing a Chrome Extension and use Chrome Identity API's to perform Facebook Oauth 2.0 authentication. Personally, I'm testing this on the latest Chrome version (64).

In principal, the login flow works fine.

However, I am annoyed that Chrome presents a **new user** a Facebook login window with **empty username and password fields** (see my screenshot), **even though he is currently logged on Facebook in another tab**. To make things even worse, there's no autocomplete available so the user has to type it in letter by letter.

[image: The problem:]

In the interest of the best user experience, I would rather expect the login screen to not ask for full credentials but just display a **"Continue as Steve"** button.

Interestingly, this happens on subsequent login attempts of the same user on the same machine - credentials do not have to be typed in anymore.

But I'd like to make the process as smooth as possible for NEW users.

The code in my background page is straightforward:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
      appId          : `${facebook_app_id}`,
      cookie         : false,
      autoLogAppEvents : false,
      status       : false,
      xfbml            : false,
      version          : 'v2.11'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));    

(...)

const TYPE = 'token';
const RANDOM_STRING = create_UUID();
const URI = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()+"fb_oauth";
const AUTH_URL = `https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/dialog/oauth?
      client_id=${facebook_app_id}
      &redirect_uri=${URI}
      &state=${RANDOM_STRING}
      &response_type=${TYPE}
      &scope=email,user_likes`;
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  url: AUTH_URL,
  interactive: true
}, function(redirectURL) {
```

**How can I optimize this?**

Have you observed the same behaviour? Can this be improved by specific settings either in the Facebook Development settings or in the way the extension launchs the login flow?

Comment: This seems to be the behaviour of the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` API, not pretty nor user friendly. You can try and manually construct a login flow with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow having `Embedded Browser OAuth Login` enabled in your facebook app settings. This will require some additional token dancing.

Comment: @holmberd yes i figure you could manufacture your own login flow in a popup, but I thought Chrome Identity API was the most secure and the right tool fit for the purpose.